# Sending data by websockets from parallel thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading, websocket, pusher

Today i have been trying to create an asynchronous task between Javascript and Django.

To create websockets and manage them, I used third party API pusher (Please make sure that question is not specific for the pusher). This system worked well at first when it was used in the main thread:

```
import pusher
import time
from django.shortcuts import render

...
def myView(request):
    ...
    def sendData():
        time.sleep(10)
        pusher_client = pusher.Pusher(
          args='values',
        )
        pusher_client.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {'message': 'Test'})
    ...
    return render('My.html', {'keys': 'values'})
```

And this is the listener in the Javascript:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

Then i wanted to create a parallel thread, So the user wouldn't wait 10 seconds to receive parallel thread. Instead, The template would be displayed and user would get alerted in 10 seconds after the request.

So i added following code which would seperate two processes:

```
import pusher
import time
from django.shortcuts import render
from threading import Thread

...
def myView(request):
    ...
    def sendData():
        time.sleep(10)
        pusher_client = pusher.Pusher(
          keys='values',
        )
        pusher_client.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {'message': 'Test'})

    th = Thread(target=sendData)
    th.daemon = True
    th.start()
    ...
    return render('My.html', {'keys': 'values'})
```

After creating another thread for the function, The function itself would be executed, However, Data could not be transmitted from Javascript...

These is my event log when i did the action:

[image: As you see, The last event is always occupied even after 10 seconds have passed]

As you see, The last event is always occupied even after 10 seconds have passed.

What could be the problem? Is problem caused by using websockets on different threads? Is there any other solution to do this?

**It seems like Thread is not working, Because, whenever i send the message from another computer node, Message is delivered in few seconds.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never used `pusher` before, but looks like it uses own servers for pushing notifications. Since your js code didn't changed, I assume the problem on server side. Did you check pusher debug console? I guess they have some kind of log about received notifications.

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk Hello, Thank you for the response, I have updated my post and now it contains event log, Final event seems to be displaying that something is always occupied even after 10 seconds.

Comment: If I understand it right, channel occupied after message was sent. Since this is a history event, you won't see it in real-time notification system. Did you check javascript console log why your channel was vacated? https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk I have added `event.wait(timeout=20)` inside the function to delay execution of code to wait until template is fully initialized. However even after 1 minute, There was no update, And this is the log: http://i.imgur.com/HTapSwu.png

Comment: But what about "Hello world" message? Is it sent by `sendData` from your daemon thread? And I can't find anything about `event.wait` in pusher documentation. Have you added it in your last attempt only or not? What is magic `20`? Is it in seconds? It's really matter that your js code start listening channel before message was sent from server side.

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk "Hello World" was sent from another computer, sendData function currently is the only the function that sends Hello World message. `wait()` is function from `threading.event`, and 20 is so that function waits 20 seconds before it executes the code. I will update question with appropriate picture.

Comment: EDIT: @SergeyZherevchuk "Hello World" message was sent when i didn't use parallel thread for the sendData(). `wait()` is a function from `threading.event`, and 20 is an argument for the function so sendData waits 20 seconds before it executes the code. I will update question with appropriate picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148057/discussion-between-sergey-zherevchuk-and-shellrox).

Comment: Just to add a little more info - you should see events received by the pusher api in the debug console, even if there are no listeners on the channel! The fact that you weren't seeing an `API MESSAGE` event in the debug console indicated that your event was never sent to pusher.

Comment: @leesio Problem was solved, It was caused by hosting's prohibition on multithreading which explains why request from the new thread was never sent to the pusher.

Comment: @ShellRox thanks for the info. I think the above is still helpful for others in this situation though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the hosting service's prohibition on multithreading. The new thread was never started, and so the event was never sent to Pusher.

(I'm quoting @ShellRox in extended comment chat.)